# Set the due date of task through a custom list workflow

Tags: workflow, custom-list, task-list

I'm trying to create a task through a workflow everytime a item is created in a custom list. The problem is when I'm trying to add a custom 'due date' that is not fixed or 'today'...

I tried to follow this question: [Set the due date on a task at time of creation using SharePoint Designer?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29411/set-the-due-date-on-a-task-at-time-of-creation-using-sharepoint-designer)

But I'm not able to handle this since there is no 'calculated' radio button...

[image: current scenario]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow below steps:

1. Add an action "Add time to date." Write your logic there and output the result into a workflow variable.

[image]

2. Assign this workflow variable value into the list item "DueDate" column.

[image]

Comment: Awesome! thanks a lot, this is a simple and clean way to do this. Thank you very much.